# Explicitly specifying parameter types in F#

Tags: types, f#, parameters, type-inference

I'm writing an F# function that factorises a number into prime factors.

```
let factors primes i =
    let mutable j = i
    for p in primes do 
        while (j>1) && (j%p=0) do 
            j <- j/p
            printfn "prime: %i" p
```

It works for `int` values of `i`, but not `int64` values. The parameter `primes` is a set of int values.

I understand why this is the case - type inference is assuming that the function only takes `int` parameters - but I want to explicitly specify the parameter type as `int64`.

Is it possible to write this function so that it will work for both `int` and `int64`?

Comment: I think there is an indentation error here - the `printfn` line should be deindented so that it occurs after the while loop

Comment: @jpalmer No, I want it to print the value of each divisor. e.g. for 8 it should print 2, 2, 2.

Comment: Looks like a case for "Type classes" concept of Haskell :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to work only on `int64` values, just replace `1` and `0` with `1L` and `0L` respectively.  jpalmer's answer covers the generic case.

Comment: That's very easy - I also need to cast the primes like `(int64)p`.

Comment: @Kirk - yes, I had been assuming your primes were already int64 values.

Answer (score 8):

You will have to do something like

```
let inline factors (primes :^a list) (i:^a) =
    let zero:^a = LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
    let one:^a = LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne
    let mutable j = i
    for p in primes do 
        while (j>one) && (j%p=zero) do 
            j <- j/p
            printfn "prime: %i" p
```

I don't have the compiler, so my syntax may be slightly off

Comment: MSDN#s online docs (with some examples, notably using literal `1`): *[Inline Functions (F#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548047.aspx)*.